# Append an item to a list in list comprehension returns none

Tags: python

```py
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = []
letter_list = [letter_list.append(item_2) for item in word_list for item_2 in item if item_2 not in letter_list]
letter_list
```

I expect the output: ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
while the actual output is [none, none, none, none, none, none, none, none, none]

Comment: `append` is a function with side-effect, so it returns `None`. You must not use such expressions in list-comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

`append` returns `None`.

If the order of the letters doesn't matter, you could use a set to filter out letters already seen, and simplify the conditions in your list comprehension:

```
letter_list = list(set(letter for word in word_list for letter in word))
```

Alternatively, because the set constructor takes an iterable, and strings are iterable, you could do this:

```
letter_list = list(set(''.join(word_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what sets are for (unless you need the order preserved, for some reason):

```
set(letter for word in word_list for letter in word)
# => {'b', 'g', 't', 'a', 'o', 'd', 'i', 'r', 'c'}
```

If you do need the order, you can do it like this:

```
letter_list = []
for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letter_list:
            letter_list.append(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `extend` instead of `append` in this case:

```py
>>> word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
>>> letter_list = []
>>> for w in word_list:
        letter_list.extend(list(w))

>>> set(letter_list)
{'b', 'r', 'g', 'd', 't', 'o', 'a', 'i', 'c'}
```